# How to solve opencv cv2.imshow() Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

Hi I installed opencv to a raspberry pi 4 (2022-04-04 Buster OS).
Here is the code I am using:

```
import cv2
    
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
success, frame = camera.read()
if not success:
    stop('camera not connected')
cv2.imshow('Window', frame)
cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

When I try to run the code, I am getting this error message:

> Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused Traceback
> (most recent call last): File "try01.py", line 7, in 
> cv2.imshow('Window', frame)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /tmp/pip-wheel-8c7uejek/opencv-python_88dbbad412c5416b992ae69de26299d6/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:635:
> error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function
> 'cvInitSystem'

Python version: 3.7.3

opencv version: 4.6.0

numpy version: 1.21.6

Any suggestions?

Comment: does your raspi even have a display attached to it?

Comment: yes, it is connected with my tv through microHDMI

Comment: please review [ask]. googling is your responsibility. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/18461 -- are you using any docker or other containerization?

Comment: I have tried this solution but it didnt work. I dont use a docker or other containerization, I just use the official raspberry Buster Lite OS

Comment: Can you run `xclock` and `xeyes` ok?

Comment: No. With both commands  appears the same error  Error: Can't open display:

Comment: So you either do not have an X11 server (GUI) running or your DISPLAY environment variable is set incorrectly.

Comment: for the display environment I used this command: export DISPLAY=:0.0 but nothing changed. How can I run an X11 server (GUI) properly?

Comment: I don't kniw how you are set up, but if you are running a text-based console, you'd need to run `startx`.

Comment: you can't run _any_ graphical programs? not an OpenCV issue then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed these steps
https://dustinpfister.github.io/2020/03/27/linux-raspbian-lite-xserver-xorg/

and then I need to run

> export DISPLAY=:0

and the problem is fixed. Thank you guys for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient information to be sure, but I suspect you are running in a text-based console rather than in a graphical desktop with GUI, such as OpenCV requires to display images.

You should be able to start the X11 server with:

```
startx
```

You would potentially need to do this after every reboot, so you may prefer the method below.

---

Or, you can run:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and select *"Boot to desktop"* rather than *"Boot to console"*. Then reboot and it will come up in GUI mode on all subsequent reboots.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a remote server and running a script using SSH, you can simply connect to the server using the -Y parameter.

```
ssh -Y user@your_ip
```

**Note**: if you're running it through VScode then use VScode for code editing and to run the file simply SSH into the server using your local terminal instead of VScode terminal using the above command and run the script